# PACEMAKER ON CENTOS 7 virtual Ip Problem

Tags: centos, ip

I am using a CentOS 7 container in Proxmox and have a problem with a virtual IP.

I have created the virtual IP using `pcs resource create cluster_vip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=10.2.12.30 cidr_netmask=23 op monitor interval=20s`
and now I am getting these errors:

```
Full list of resources:

cluster_vip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2): Stopped
Resource Group: grp_zabbix_httpd
zabbix_server (systemd:zabbix-server): Stopped
httpd (systemd:httpd): Stopped

Failed Actions:
* cluster_vip_monitor_0 on zabbix1 ‘not installed’ (5): call=5, status=complete, exitreason=’Setup problem: couldn’t find command: ip’,
last-rc-change=’Sat Aug 25 17:09:23 2018′, queued=0ms, exec=15ms
```

is up to date

```
 yum install iproute
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirror.netcologne.de
 * epel: ftp.nluug.nl
 * extras: mirror.wiuwiu.de
 * updates: mirror.netcologne.de
Package iproute-4.11.0-14.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

# ip route

default via 10.2.12.1 dev eth0
10.2.12.0/23 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.13.44
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1088

# ip a|grep "inet "

inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet 10.2.13.44/23 brd 10.2.13.255 scope global eth0
    inet 10.2.12.30/23 scope global secondary eth0

# netstat -rn

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.2.12.1       0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.2.12.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
```

`pcs resource cleanup cluster_vip` has not brought a solution. What can I do?

Comment: command -v ip
/usr/sbin/ip

Comment: [mystrace](https://workupload.com/file/6GJtrSAx)

Comment: It is not entirely clear whether this is question about a zabbix or pacemaker error.

Answer (score 1):

Need to `yum install which` per http://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1460457

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error suggests that the commandline tool `ip` is not installed. Try executing this command as `root`:

```
yum install iproute
```